# Ignore serialversionUID by getting declaredFields with reflection

Tags: java, java-8

Is there a whay to ignore the Field "serialversionUID" by this code (maybe with filter)

```
obj.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
```

for information its the only static field. maybe its possible to ignore static fields

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Sure it is possible. What's the question? You actually answered it yourself

Comment: Think more about your actual task. If `static` fields are inappropriate in general, then ignore `static` fields in general. Otherwise, use the exact properties of the field you want to ignore, like the mentioned name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Arrays.stream(Test.class.getDeclaredFields()).filter(f -> !f.getName().equals("serialVersionUID")).collect(Collectors.toList())
```

**Stream** with **filter** to filter *serialversionUID*

Comment: Note that it's usually `serialVersionUID` (with capital `v`).

Comment: It’s preferable to use `Arrays.stream` rather than `Stream.of` if you have an array rather than a variable argument list. This avoids confusion between creating a stream of *n* elements of type `X` and creating a stream of *one* element of type `X[]`…

Comment: Thanks TagirValeev and Holger

Answer (score 0):

To ignore all static fields you can do the following:

```
for(Field f : obj.getClass().getDeclaredFields()){

  if(!Modifier.isStatic(f.getModifiers())){

     ...do your thing

  }
}
```